# Facebook Presto unable to retrieve data from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight, presto, azure-blob-storage

I have an **Azure HDInsight Hadoop Cluster** and a **parquet** file stored on an **Azure blob** from which I created a Hive table, called **hive_table**.

I am able to execute hive sql queries successfully.

Next, when using **Facebook Presto**, the **hive_table** is visible and I can describe its schema.

However, when it comes to executing sql queries the result is always 0.

Inside *presto/etc/catalog* I have defined *hive.properties* like this:

```
    connector.name=hive-hadoop2
    hive.metastore.uri=thrift://hn0-vlad-h.ao051s5okc4epeushe1jjexxqg.bx.internal.cloudapp.net:9083, thrift://hn1-vlad-h.ao051s5okc4epeushe1jjexxqg.bx.internal.cloudapp.net:9083
    hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml
```

I have also set the right security credentials inside *core-site.xml*.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Hive queries return results and not 0?

Comment: Yes, they return the rows in the db.

Comment: Mirel, did you ever get Presto working on Blob Storage?

Comment: @BenHumphrey I was able to describe just the schema (fetching the rows still returns 0). However, I haven't tried in a few months so things might have changed. Let me know if it works for you.